# What is the notified-CompliancePage page?

Tags: 404, web-crawlers

I sometimes have bots (I assume) hitting pages such as:

/notified-CompliancePage?aHR0cDovL3d3dy5teXBpdm90cy5jb20vZGFpbHlub3Rlcw==

/verify-CompliancePage?aHR0cDovL3d3dy5teXBpdm90cy5jb20vZGFpbHlub3Rlcw==

Any idea what these pages are intended for or what the bots are looking for?

Referring source: http://compliance.ubp.internet/notify-CompliancePage... which is obviously not going to resolve because there is no .internet TLD

Comment: This could be a weird example of [referrer spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spam)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit of digging turns up [this old thread from Webmaster World](http://www.webmasterworld.com/search_engine_spiders/3859463.htm), another thread from [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/104688/what-is-notified-splashpage). The conclusion seems to be that it's caused by a bot looking for installations of a Bluecoat product called ProxySG to attack.

> Seems a security product called [ProxySG](http://www.bluecoat.com/products/proxysg) uses requests like
>   verify-SNL_Splash. Meant to be on the LAN side but apparently it may
>   be possible to attack the product and the external hits you are seeing
>   may be bot's probing to find users of ProxySG.

[Googling the term](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&ix=seb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=notified-CompliancePage#q=notified-CompliancePage&hl=en&rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&prmd=imvns&ei=5ydeT9uqJYz38QOq3oDKBA&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=fc458632c6d138f5&biw=1920&bih=955&ix=seb) shows a lot of odd results including some sites which have dedicated sales and advertising pages to 'notified-CompliancePage' so it seems like a common enough problem that spammers are taking advantage of the confusion...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more likeley that it's an example of this gone bad:  https://bto.bluecoat.com/tech-brief/creating-notification-policies-coaching-splash-and-compliance

BlueCoat can be configured to show a notification to the user that they have to accept before moving on to the destination page.  In my example, it's sending almost everyone who gets one of those to a 404 page on the destination site, because something is wrong/off in the redirect.